# angular-tooltips trying to customize the message

Tags: angularjs

I am using this library : angular-tooltips

And I have this code :

```
tooltipsConfProvider.configure('tooltipsConfProvider',{
            'smart':true,
            'size':'large',
            'speed': 'slow',
            'tooltipTemplateUrlCache': true,
            'tooltipTemplateUrl': 'sources/test/tooltip.template.html'
        });
```

My tooltip is blank while i have some text in my template, any idea why?

the doc : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tooltips

Thanks

Comment: Do you by any  chance get a 404 that it cannot find the template?

Comment: no, it does not even work with hard coded text using this param tooltip-template. but this works in html page <a href="#" tooltips tooltip-template="tooltip">Tooltip me</a>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure here - but try to tooltipTemplateUrlCache to "false".
Also, can you provide an example when trying to use the tooltip itself?

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me just check if you are missing something...

https://plnkr.co/edit/QLQRi7a521XVzhgIiNCH?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <a href="#" tooltips tooltip-template="tooltip now" tooltip-smart=true>Tooltip me</a>
  </body>
```

Comment: that way it works for me! try to use tooltipTemplateUrl

Comment: Check this one its working.....   https://plnkr.co/edit/hVC3NiNApNSiradlLPni?p=preview

Comment: It was because the template file needs to be of html type...include your tip inside some p tag

Comment: Now I see the mistake I made, I was trying to set the tooltip-template-url in configure

Comment: And I guess you are wrong...as I think you can set this attribute even in configure bro..